# Pass method parameter with custom annotation of AOP

Tags: java, aspectj, spring-aop

I have defined annotation with 
`@Target(ElementType.METHOD)`
`@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)`

When I use custom annotation under method which i want to aspect, and then i want to get the parameters(they are Object, not string, int ant byte) of the method signature.

is there simple way to get method parameter with custom annotation of AOP?

Comment: If my solution works for you and can be regarded as helpful, please upvote it for the support ~ thank you ;)

Comment: @Hearen is it possible specified exception type? such as: 
`@AfterThrowing("@annotation(methodTimer), throwing = DownstreamException")`
`@AfterThrowing("@annotation(methodTimer), throwing = downstreamException")`
`@AfterThrowing("@annotation(methodTimer)", throwing="DownstreamException")` 
`@AfterThrowing("@annotation(methodTimer)", throwing="downstreamException")`

Comment: perhaps you can turn to GlobalExceptionHandler instead

Comment: @Hearen thank you for your help, the below is my expected.    
`@AfterThrowing(value = "(@annotation(LogRequest))", throwing = "downstreamCallException")  public void logRequestWithBusinessError(JoinPoint joinPoint, DownstreamCallException downstreamCallException)`

Comment: ....it seems you should start a new question for that ;) not easy to understand the background here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple demo can as:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MethodTimer {
}
```

And the aspect handler:

```
@Aspect
@Slf4j
@Component
public class TimeCounterAspect {
    @Around("@annotation(methodTimer)")
    public Object logMethodRequests(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, MethodTimer methodTimer)
            throws Throwable {
        Long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
        Method method = signature.getMethod();
        String methodName = method.getName();
        Object[] myArgs = joinPoint.getArgs();
        Object obj = null;
        try {
            obj = joinPoint.proceed();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {
                log.info("Retrieving timeCost: {} ms in Method: {} args: {}",
                System.currentTimeMillis() - start, methodName, Arrays.deepToString(myArgs));
        }
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the arguments via `ProceedingJoinPoint`:

```
@Around("execution(@com.path.annotation.YourAnnotation * *(..)) && @annotation(annotation)")
public Object execute(final ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, final YourAnnotation annotation) throws Throwable {
    Object result = pjp.proceed();
    // Here is the method arguments
    Object[] args = pjp.getArgs();

    return result;
}
```